# How to add to a variable in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I don't have the greatest knowledge of XSLT and am stuck with a bit of a problem.

I want to assign a value to an XSLT variable based on the total of the values of some variables coming from some XML.

Example of what I'm currently trying:

```
<xsl:variable name="MyValue">
  <xsl:for-each select="/one/two/three/items">
     <xsl:value-of select="$MyValue + /one/two/three/items/itemsvalue"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

Any ideas on how to make this possible would be great!

Comment: "*how to make this possible*" How to make what possible? It's not at all clear what you're trying to accomplish here - and the code that cannot work is not making it any clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to loop, and you don't need to add to a variable (indeed, variables are immutable in XSLT).

Instead, operate directly against the input XML document, and use **[`sum()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-sum)** to add up the string values (converted to numbers) of the nodes of interest:

```
 <xsl:value-of select="sum(/one/two/three/items/itemsvalue)"/>
```